# Wanted to make sure you “had” or “have” what you need to make a start

Tags: tenses, past-tense, sequence-of-tenses

Would you be able to explain which one is grammatically correct, or whether both can be grammatically correct depending on the context?

Comment: I disagree about the need to harmonize the verb forms. The preterite forms of the verbs are being used to express modal remoteness moreso than past time. The preterite forms add politeness and deference to the question. You can make one or both verbs preterite, depending on the level of politeness.

Comment: Depends on the context!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either is fine, generally speaking, in casual speech. There is a subtle different. If you say "I wanted to make sure you had what you need..." you are confirming that the person at some point in the past had what they needed. If you say "I wanted to make sure you have what you need..." you are checking if they have what they need right now.

So to offer a contrast, let's say you need a notepad to make a start. At 9am someone gave you a notebook, and then at 10am someone took that notebook away. It is now noon. The answer to the question "I wanted to make sure you had what you needed ..." is "yes I had what I needed (though I don't at the current time)." The answer to the question "I wanted to make sure you have what you need..." the answer is "yes, I have what I need."

So it is a subtle distinction, that is sometimes useful. But most likely, functionally you want to say "have" here, since that is actually what matters.

FWIW, if you were asked if you "had" what you needed, in the above scenario, it would probably be considered pedantic, not to say counterproductive, to say yes. In fact the phrasing of the question suffers from the same thing. Really the question should be: "I want to make sure you have what you need.... do you?". Here they are using "wanted" in precisely the same way. You could, for example, have wanted to know if they had it at 11:30am, but now, at noon? Well now you don't care any more.

Moreover, this kind of casual disconnect is further emphasized by the fact that you are making a declarative statement about what you want, or wanted, rather than directly asking the question: "Do you have what you need...".

However, for sure in casual speech, "I wanted to make sure you had what you needed" would certainly convey the meaning that you intend, and provoke the response you sought, even if what this statement literally says is probably not what you actually meant.

Comment: Thanks Fraser! Your raised a very interesting point: in casual conversations, focus on the likely intended meaning. Bearing that in mind, would you agree that, colloquially, the following is likely to have the same intended meaning in the context of a past occurrence: “sorry to keep you waiting” and “sorry to have kept you waiting” (even though grammatically the latter is more accurate in that it happened in the past and has a continuing effect and so it should be expressed in a perfect tense)?

Comment: So, again they have subtly different meanings. "sorry to have kept you waiting" is in a perfect tense, meaning that the action is completed. So this one implies that you are no longer keeping me waiting. "sorry to keep you waiting" can, and in fact often does, mean that I am still keeping your waiting, though it is open enough to encompass the same meaning as the perfect tense. This is actually a meaningful distinction that does matter. "Sorry to have kept you waiting but I can help you now", "Sorry to keep you waiting but it'll be another ten minutes" would contrast the two effectively. HTH.

Comment: BTW, whoever downvoted my answer: it is kind of rude to do that without offering any comment on why you downvoted it. I could certainly have made a mistake that justifies such a response but if you don't tell anyone what my error was then you are offering no value to the community.

Comment: Super! Thanks Fraser - yes the downvote is unjustified and rude!